# Grouping user stories based on release

Tags: json, rally

I am able to filter all of the user stories based on a start Release and an end Release, but I now want to group these user stories based on the specific Release they are in. For example, If my start Release is 35 and my end Release is 37, I want to take all the user stories I got from the code below and save them into 35, 36, and 37 based on where they reside. I was thinking if there was a way to loop through each release between two dates and save the data as I go, it would work.

```
   // Filters all user stories between start release date and end release date
    var iterationFilters = [
        {
            property: 'Iteration.StartDate',
            operator: '>=',
            value: StartDate 
        },
        {
            property: 'Iteration.EndDate',
            operator: '<=',
            value: EndDate 
        },
    ];

    var defectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'User Story',
        autoLoad: true,                      

        filters : iterationFilters,

        listeners: {
            load: function(myStore, myData) {
                console.log(myData)
            },
            scope: this                        
        },
        fetch: ['CreationDate','FormattedID']

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the intent to show it in a grid?  If so you could use this example to get you pretty close: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/groupable-grid

Otherwise if you just need to manipulate the raw data, I'd just use the groupBy function provided by lodash.

```
var storiesByRelease = _.groupBy(defectStore.getRange(), function(story) {
    return story.get('Release')._refObjectName;
});
```